# angularjs directive scope function not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Have created a directive to dynamically include the header.html in the master index html file.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('header', function() {

        var directive = {};
        directive.restrict = 'AE';
        directive.replace = true;
        directive.scope = {};
        directive.templateUrl = "header.html";
        directive.link = function postLink($scope, $element, $attrs, $resource) {
                  $scope.version = "1.1.1.1";
                  $scope.getusername = function() {
              $scope.username = "pals";
              };
              };
        return directive;
});
```

header.html

```
<div ng-init="getusername()">
  <p>
    This part of the hader is always here
  </p>
  <p>
    User {{username}} is logged in :D
  </p>
  <p>
  {{version}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Complete code written @ http://plnkr.co/edit/Iau6Fu?p=preview

The scope variable ($scope.version) is working.

But the scope function call ($scope.getusername) is not happening.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code relies on `ngInit` in the template to execute a method called `getusername()` on the scope. `getusername()` is placed on the scope in the post-link function, which is executed *after* `ngInit` is evaluated. So `ngInit` never invokes `getusername()`.

To fix this, place `getusername()` on the scope in the directive's controller so it is available to `ngInit`...

```
directive.controller = function($scope) {
    $scope.getusername = function() {
        $scope.username = "pals";
    };
};
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fW6jeYKPHfzR8GsGApq1?p=preview)

Please place the relevant code in your question rather than in a plunker.